# Javascript: String replace problem

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I've got a string which contains `q="AWORD"` and I want to replace `q="AWORD"` with `q="THEWORD"`. However, I don't know what AWORD is.. is it possible to combine a string and a regex to allow me to replace the parameter without knowing it's value? This is what I've got thus far...

```
globalparam.replace('q="/+./"', 'q="AWORD"');
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you have is just a string, not a regular expression. I think this is what you want:

```
globalparam.replace(/q=".+?"/, 'q="THEWORD"');
```

I don't know how you got the idea why you have to "combine" a string and a regular expression, but a regex does not need to exist of wildcards only. A regex is like a pattern that can contain wildcards but otherwise will try to match the exact characters given.

The expression shown above works as follows:

- `q="`: Match the characters `q`, `=` and `"`.
- `.+?"`: Match any character (`.`) up to (and including) the next `"`. There must be at least one character (`+`) and the match is non-greedy (`?`), meaning it tries to match as few characters as possible. Otherwise, if you used `.+"`, it would match all characters up to the *last* quotation mark in the string.

[Learn more about regular expressions](http://regular-expressions.info/).

Answer (score 2):

Felix's answer will give you the solution, but if you actually want to construct a regular expression using a string you can do it this way:

```
var fullstring = 'q="AWORD"';
var sampleStrToFind = 'AWORD';

    var mat = 'q="'+sampleStrToFind+'"';
    var re = new RegExp(mat);
    var newstr =  fullstring.replace(re,'q="THEWORD"');

alert(newstr);
```

`mat =` the regex you are building, combining strings or whatever is needed.

`re =` RegExp constructor, if you wanted to do global, case sensitivity, etc do it here.

The last line is `string.replace(RegExp,replacement);`